# how to sandwitch an absolutely positioned div between absolutely positioned parent and child divs

Tags: html, css

In the following code, I have 3 `divs` all are `position: absolute`.

I want `div1` between `div2` and `div3`. To achieve this I have given `z-index` as follows: `div1 (0), div2 (-1), div3(1)` but after doing this, I am getting `div1` on the top instead of middle. I understand this is happening because of how stacking context work and `div3` is stacking wrt `div2`.

**My question is:** how can I put `div1` between `div2` and `div3`.

Pls note I can't change following things:

1. I can't change `HTML` code
2. all divs must be `position: absolute`

```css
div {
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}

.div1 {
    background: red;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 50px;
}

.div2 {
    width: 100px;
    background: green;
    z-index: -1;
}

.div3 {
    top: 20%;
    width: 75px;
    background: blue;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    div1
</div>

<div class="div2">
    div2

    <div class="div3">
        div3
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove z-index from div2 (don't define any z-index there) and add z-index:1 to div1 and div3